# how to display Firestore Timestamp in Month/ Year format in angular?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I am getting data from firestore collection and displaying on a chart, however as the date is in timestamp, it is displaying as such. I want to render as MM/YYYY , so how can I do it?

```
 const date = this.data.map((item) => item.weightDate);
```

This is where I am getting the date to be displayed.

Comment: Convert the Firestore timestamp into a JavaScript Date, then format that date as the string you want.  Both of these should be easy to find out how to do with web searches.

Answer (score 1):

As @Doug Stevenson mentioned in the comments that you have to Convert Timestamp to Javascript Date Object. Then format the date object as per your liking.

You can use **[Timestamp.toDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.timestamp#timestamptodate)** method to convert Firestore Timestamp to Javascript Date Object.

```
const date = data().weightDate.toDate();
const formattedDate = `${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getFullYear()}`; // Your Required formatted date.
```

#### Update :

Here is the live example for you.

```js
const firestore_date = new Date("2015-03-25"); //mocking date
const date = `${firestore_date.getMonth() + 1}/${firestore_date.getFullYear()}`;
console.log(date);
```

Comment: I need to use 'map' as in  const date = this.data.map((item) => item.weightDate); If I had .toDate as  const date = this.data.map((item) => item.weightDate).toDate(); Getting error as its an array Property 'toDate' does not exist on type 'any[]'

Comment: it only renders seconds and  nanoseconds instead of only MM/YYYY that I want

Comment: I have added live example for you in my answer hope it will help solve your issue.